Running fiddler proxy and connecting to wireguard
I am connecting to wireguard vpn on a windows machine

On the same machine I am running fiddler 4 proxy on port 8888

When I am not connected to wireguard I am able to browse through proxy
The issue is when I connect to wireguard server and try to browse through proxy
not able to browse
